# I Think My Graphics Card Changed

Tags: mac, graphics

I opened System Information today only to find that my graphics card name has changed from Intel 4000 (or something like that) to AMD Radion: [image: About Display]

I don't think I'm going crazy.

EDIT: I was right! Here it is showing Intel 3000: http://icap.me/i/yEdDGcjR1B.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most recent 15" MacBook Pros have dual graphics cards — one integrated into the CPU (the Intel 3000), and one discrete card (the Radeon). It switches dynamically based on what programs are running and how they use the GPU.

Some more info from Apple:

- [MacBook Pro: How to determine which graphics card is in use](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4152)
- [MacBook Pro: How to set graphics performance](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4110)
- [MacBook Pro: About automatic graphics switching and OpenGL applications](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4044)

Comment: a funny one for a change :)

Comment: It changed to the Radeon when I exported something from After Effects. Makes sense.

Comment: Alternatively you can use tools like GfxCardStatus to manually select which graphics to use.